# Is there a reason to buy a 0% yield bond?

Tags: bonds, economics, yield

Right now I can get a 1yr government bond that yields 0%.  Is there any reason to buy such a bond?  E.G. If the broker holding my accounts goes out of business is my "perceived low risk portion" of my portfolio any safer in a government 0% bond than it is in a money market account held by my broker?

Answer (score 3):

0% bonds are desirable for some individuals. It depends on your situation. 0% bonds are usually sold well below par value (eg a 100$ face value bond for 2020 might sell for 90$ today) Hence, your gains will be CAPITAL GAINS. A similar investment paying interest would be taxed as INCOME, and smaller portion of capital gains. In many countries (US, Canada) Capital gains are taxed at a more favourable rate then income. This is especially true when holding these investments in corporations.

Comment: The question stipulates a zero-percent YIELD bond. Which should mean it's selling *above* par value if it has a non-zero rate (as government bonds tend to).

Comment: you are confusing yields and coupon rates. It does not say that these are zero coupon bonds just that they have a yield (probably YTM) of 0%. At the correct price a zero coupon bond could have zero yield but shouldn't under "normal" market conditions.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

There are a number of reasons that institutions buy these bonds but as an individual you're likely better off in a low-yield cash account.

By contrast, there *would* be a reason to hold a low-yield (non-zero) bond rather than an alternative low-yield product.